# Ruby/Rhomobile: parse directory string representation

Tags: ruby, regex, string, parsing, rhomobile

I have a string that looks like this: `{"whatever-field"=>"gghyduudud"}`
I'd like to parse it so that it becomes a hash.

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a String that's a Hash. In other languages this is also called a Dictionary (key => value).

Please elaborate on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @three I think the string contains `"{\"whatever-field\"=>\"ggh...\"}"`

Comment: @Svarog By dictionary you mean Hash? Afaik "Dictionary" is Python.

Comment: Yeah, I guess hash is what I mean, am pretty new to ruby and come from C#/Java world. And yes, I have a string representation of the hash, and would like to parse it into a hash.

Comment: still not clear could you post some more advanced sample ?

Comment: Is my answer what you mean? Convert the string representation of the Hash into the actual Hash?

Comment: is the origin of the data safe? (so you can use eval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval`, but only if the data source is absolutely reliable:

```
>> eval('{"whatever-field"=>"gghyduudud"}')
=> {"whatever-field"=>"gghyduudud"}
```

Comment: That could be very risky, although it is the only way if it contains other data types. Maybe you can validate the data on a regex first?

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh: That's why I said "aboslute reliable". If it comes from a user is no good, if you are sending it your own string it's ok.

Comment: Yes. That is why all of the computer literature warns against ever using explicit eval. It seems that `eval` is considered bad practice. Here it makes a lot of sense though. Just thought it was worth mentioning. Of course, if the data must come from outside, you could wrap this in its own thread with a safe level of 4. But that seems a bit cumbersome for just parsing strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
dictionary=Hash[*(dict_str[1..dict_str.length-2].split("=>").map {|strval| strval[1..strval.length-2]})]
```

That will work as long as you want the keys and values as strings. Its a bit long, but it worked for me.

Comment: `Hash[*(str.delete('{"}').split('=>'))]`is a bit shorter.

Comment: I forget about `delete`. Thanks.